# i have a String contains a repeated word like 72 times and i want to split the text into many strings that contains substrings between that word

Tags: java, string, function, file, file-manager

I have a String contains a repeated word like 72 times and i want to split the text into many substrings each contains the string between the first occurance of the word and the second occurance then the second substring contains the string between second occurance and the third one and so on until reaching the last occurance
//my sample data like (the yellow sun , the green tree , the big house )
//consider the is the repeated word

```
public class wordOutput {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
      
      
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\output3.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = buf.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        while(line != null){ 
          sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
          line = buf.readLine(); 
          }
        String fileAsString = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Contents : " + fileAsString);
          String keyword="AGE";
        int index = fileAsString.indexOf(keyword);
        while (index >=0){
            System.out.println("Index : "+index);
            index = fileAsString.indexOf(keyword, index+keyword.length())   ;
         
           
    
          
        
        } int last=fileAsString.length();
        
          System.out.println("last " +last);
         
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to use properly indented code formatting? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use  `String[] arr = String.split("repeatedWordHere")` and you can just ignore the first and last element of array

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would have been great if you would have given sample data but, based on your statement, you can use **split(String regex)** method available for String objects.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
      
      
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\output3.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = buf.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        while(line != null){ 
          sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
          line = buf.readLine(); 
          }
        String fileAsString = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Contents : " + fileAsString);
          String keyword="AGE";
          printDelimitedValues(fileAsString, keyword); // calling method to split here
         
        }
 
 public static void printDelimitedValues(String str , String delimiter) {
        
        String strArr[] = str.split(delimiter);
        for(String substr:strArr) {
            System.out.println(substr);
        }
        
    }
```

So if sample data is this: **The quick brown fox AGE The quick brown fox AGE the quick brown fox AGE**
Keyword is AGE
The output would be :

The quick brown fox

The quick brown fox

The quick brown fox

Comment: the sample data would be as the big white house , the green tree , the yellow sun

Comment: only the is repeated and i want each sentence to be in a single line

Comment: Change this System.out.println(substr);  to System.out.print(substr); this will give output in 1 line

Comment: If the input is Sun Moon and Stars then the whole dynamics change neither the input can be stored in one single string nor the output. You would have to read the data from the given file in chunks and write to another file or console in chunks with sufficient amount of memory to sustain the data as buffer in memory

Comment: i mean each sentence in a different line